# Conversion of log-transformed SD

Tags: standard-deviation, logarithm

In a meta-analysis of some research work, there are many situations in which the literature reported the mean values and their corresponding standard deviations in log-transformed forms.

The question is: how can I transform back the SD to the normal values, is there any formula or equation that could help in this regard?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you [searched our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lognormal+mean+sd)?  I'm confident the answer is already here.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a good reason why these statistics are being reported in the log scale. Usual practice is to then do all calculations in the log scale and only back-transform the final result (e.g. point estimate and confidence limits)

A key aspect is that for a [log-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) variable, the mean and standard deviation are not independent in the original scale. This is easily demonstrated by comparing the densities of log-normal variables with the same log-scale mean (here $\mu=2$) but different log-scale standard deviation ($\sigma=1,\frac{3}{2},2)$, first in the log scale and then original:

[image: log-normal densities]

I don't know of a way to exactly recover the original standard deviation estimate $\hat\sigma_o$ without the individual observations. My primary recommendation would be to do your meta-analysis in the log scale that the statistics were provided in: the original $\hat\sigma_o$, even if you were to know it exactly, would most likely not be a good summary measure for such data (look back to that second plot above).

You *can* approximate the coefficient of variation $\frac{\sigma_o}{\mu_o}$ in the original scale however, and if you know the original mean estimate $\hat\mu_o$ this lets you approximate the original $\hat\sigma_o$. These MLEs are not unbiased and they rely heavily on the data being accurately log-normal (rarely true), so I would not recommend you proceed like this. The formula is quite straightforward though: $\frac{\sigma_o}{\mu_o}\approx \sqrt{e^{\sigma^2}-1}$, with $\sigma$ the log-scale standard deviation. Multiplying $\sqrt{e^{\hat{\sigma}^2}-1}$ by the original $\hat\mu_o$ nets you an approximated original $\hat\sigma_o$.

A quick simulation example to highlight that this approximation gets worse as $\mu$ and/or $\sigma$ gets larger, even when the data follows an exact theoretical log-normal distribution:

```r
## Convert log SD to original CV
log_sd_to_cv <- function(log_sd) sqrt(exp(log_sd**2)-1)

## Compare exact to approximated original SD
set.seed(1)
mapply(function(log_mu, log_sigma) {
   x <- rlnorm(1E2, log_mu, log_sigma)
   c("approx" = log_sd_to_cv(sd(log(x))) * mean(x),
     "exact" = sd(x))
}, log_mu = c(2, 3, 3), log_sigma = c(0.5, 0.75, 1))

>        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
> approx 4.07 21.17 47.23
> exact  4.00 22.42 42.38
```

In summary, what you want to do is *kind of* possible (if you know the original mean), but there's several reasons why you should probably stick to the log scale instead.

Comment: Re "you can never exactly recover the original standard deviation σo without the individual observations." Really? Given the mean and sd of the logarithms, you have two equations in two unknowns.  They have at least one solution -- and usually just one solution.  And it can be computed exactly rather than approximately.  Are you perhaps using "mean" and "sd" with multiple meanings?  At times you seem to be referring to parameters and other times to statistics or perhaps estimators.

Comment: @whuber I've qualified the statement, though I could find no sources claiming otherwise. I've also tried to separate parameters from their estimates. Plugging in the log-scale mean/sd into $\sqrt{[exp(\sigma^2)-1]\times exp(2\mu+\sigma^2)}$ doesn't require original scale statistics but also doesn't result in the same value as calculating the standard deviation of the original sample? The key message is still that staying in the log scale is probably the better idea, to the point that I could find much more literature on the inverse problem (estimating log statistics from original).

Comment: I agree with the key message, but am concerned it might get lost in the ambiguous uses of statistical terms.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this handy answer, highly appreciated it.